# Can I pass a property list as &key arguments to a function?

Tags: common-lisp

Is there's a way to pass to a function a property list as argument in a way similar to this:

```
(defun sum (&key x y) (+ x y))
(sum '(:x 10 :y 20))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To call a function with the arguments coming from a list use [APPLY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm#apply):

```
CL-USER > (apply #'sum '(:x 10 :y 20))
30
```

Also this works:

```
CL-USER > (apply #'sum :x '(10 :y 20))
30

CL-USER > (apply #'sum :x 10 '(:y 20))
30

CL-USER > (apply #'sum :x 10 :y '(20))
30

CL-USER > (apply #'sum :x 10 :y 20 '())
30
```

Note that the variable `call-arguments-limit` still *applies*. The number of arguments in a function call that an implementation supports is usually limited. Thus applying a function with a long list of arguments might not work. Note that for example in ABCL this value is just 50 (fifty).